# How to derive joint CDF using definition of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am reading the article "An Introduction to Copulas" [http://www.columbia.edu/~mh2078/QRM/Copulas.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Emh2078/QRM/Copulas.pdf) by Martin Haugh. I'd love to have some help to understand an example (page 2) that is quoted below:
[image]

Can anyone help me understand how the equation (3) above is derived? This is obviously a beginner question, but I feel it can be a good opportunity for me to better understand some of the basic concepts. Thanks!

Comment: For (i) $x_2 \le x_1$ it is easy as you need both $Y$ and $Z$ be be no more than $x_2$ so $F(x_2)^2$ which is what (3) says